# Can't set csrf_token as hidden input value

Tags: html, django, vue.js

I'm really confused. When I use *csrf_token* as itself e.g `<div>{{csrf_token}}</div>` it works perfectly and gives **output** like `<div>aObwmGR5FiCGnfffpeZhbtMtFCFEMyjTKc0QnYT8FZcF9j9oqz5MzYnqDgcVyBBq</div>`, but when I use it in my `input` field as a `value` it doesn't work..

This: `<input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" value="{{csrf_token}}" v-model="csrf_token">` gives me this **output**: `<input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" value="">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can't do that... Your **{{csrf_token}}** render that value by **server**. (Seem you use Laravel and Vuejs) but **v-model="csrf_token"** value render by javascript (Vuejs). So, your csrf_token is of course null value. Change you code in Vue Instance like this:

```
data : {
    csrf_token : 'blala...'
}
```

And set input like this :value="csrf_token". You will get input value is **blala...** that what i mention before, you csrf_token is render by Vuejs

Comment: I use Django 2.0.4, and in other cases it works well. Just this one case is corrupted.

Comment: Yes, that's all correct. It's caused by **v-model**, which takes **initial** data from **Vue** instance, what is explained well [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage).